# Is it possible to create a time based nft where there is a fixed expiry date?

Tags: nft, time

I'm looking to create a set where after a set period of time (a week, a month, a year) the token expires and all its value is wiped. Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. To accomplish this, you would start with your preferred NFT standard and a timestamp on creation. It also depends what you mean by having its value 'wiped'. Value is something determined by buyers and sellers in a market. So assuming 'wiped' means destroyed, you can have the NFT destroyed after your deadline has passed. One caveat is that you would need someone actually call the NFT to self-destruct after deadline is passed.

To implement a deadline of 365 days, you set the constructor to have something like:

uint _start;

constructor() {
_start = block.timestamp;
}

function checkTime() external {
if(block.timestamp >= _start + 365 days) {
selfdestruct(owner);
}
}

Then after 365 days, you or an automated script needs to call the contract "checkTime()" and the NFT will be gone.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for answering the question. I am fairly new to coding so how much do you want to teach me the basics of how to do this?